# Why does 'loadWindow' work here when 'window' doesn't?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I was able to solve my problem with some trial and error, but I'm not really sure why it works. I have two main classes - AboutWindowController and MainView - and I was having trouble getting the AboutWindow nib to load.

Here's something that didn't work (in MainView.m):

```
#import "MainView.h"
#import "AboutWindowController"
...

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        AboutWindowController *aboutWindowController = [[AboutWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"AboutWindowController"];
        [aboutWindowController window];
        ...
    }
return self;
}
...
```

However, this did work (using loadWindow instead of window)

```
#import "MainView.h"
#import "AboutWindowController"
...

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        AboutWindowController *aboutWindowController = [[AboutWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"AboutWindowController"];
        [aboutWindowController loadWindow];
        ...
    }
return self;
}
...
```

The documentation says I shouldn't call loadWindow and that window calls it anyway, but the window did not appear. After playing around for a bit, I was able to fix the problem by adding a property to the implementation file, as follows:

```
#import "MainView.h"
#import "AboutWindowController.h"

@interface MainView 
@property (strong, nonatomic) AboutWindowController *aboutWindowController;
@end

@implementation MainView

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _aboutWindowController = [[AboutWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"AboutWindowController"];
        [_aboutWindowController window];
    ...
    }
return self;
}
...
```

I'm wondering why adding the property fixed everything. Can someone shed light on this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first two cases, the reference to your `AboutWindowController` object is held in a local variable. When that local variable goes out of scope, ARC releases the reference. If that's the last reference, the window controller is deallocated, at which point it releases the window. If that was the last reference to the window, then the window is deallocated and removed from the screen (probably before you ever got a chance to see it).

By assigning the reference to a strong instance variable, you ensure that the window controller sticks around long enough to see the window.

I'm not sure why it worked when you called `-loadWindow`. It could be that `-loadWindow` effectively leaks a reference to the window (or the controller) when it's called directly (which would be one reason that you're not supposed to do that).

Comment: Got it! I had a feeling it had something to do with ARC cleaning things up. For future reference, is there an easy way to test to see if objects are currently instantiated or cleaned up? I'm sure I'll run into a problem like this again.

Comment: There's no programmatic way to test whether a pointer points to a real object or whether it's dangling. You could override `-dealloc` in your class and have it log a message. You could run your app under the Allocations template and look at what has been done with instances of your class and whether any are still "live".